# Jquery ajax post multiple rows with inputs - just the first row of input values posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a big problem, and I don't found any solution to solve this.
The problem: I would like to post the values of rows when I click to the update button. (If I click to first row update button, then post the values of first row inputs, if I click to second row update button, then post the values of second row inputs and so on)

Now just posts the values of first row inputs, indifferent which row update button clicked. (Because I don't know how can I use the form id at the javascript part of code)

There are multiple forms (for each rows), but I don't know how can I use the id of form ({$formcount}) when I try to post values of lastname, firstname and importance values at javascript part of code. I hope that someone could help for me because I am going crazy. (I viewed a lot of similar problems and solutions at stackoverflow, but I can't solve the problem). Many thanks.

```
<table>
    {counter start=0 print=false name=fcount}
    {foreach item=teamplayer from=$squad}
    {counter assign=formcount name=fcount}
    {if $teamplayer.position != 0}
    <tr>
        <form action="edit_clubs.php" id="{$formcount}" name="upd" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

            <input type="hidden" name="myseason" id="season" value="{$season}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="update" id="update" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="myplayer" id="myplayer" value="{$teamplayer.id_person}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="myclub" id="myclub" value="{$club.id}" />
            <td><input type="text" id="lastname{$teamplayer.id_person}" name="lastname" value="{$teamplayer.lastname}" size="8" maxlength="8"></td>

            <td><input type="text" id="firstname{$teamplayer.id_person}" name="firstname" value="{$teamplayer.firstname}" size="8" maxlength="8"></td>

            <td><input type="text" id="importance{$teamplayer.id_person}" name="importance" value="{$teamplayer.importance}" size="8" maxlength="8"></td>
            <td>

                <a data-target="#upd" class="update" data-myseason="{$season}" data-myplayer="{$teamplayer.id_person}" data-myclub="{$club.id}">Update</a>
                <div class="loader"></div>
            </td>


    </tr>
    {/if}

    </form>
    {/foreach}
</table>

<script type = "text/javascript"
src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" > < /script>


    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    $('.update').click(function() {

        var myplayer = $(this).attr('data-myplayer');
        var myseason = $(this).attr('data-myseason');
        var myclub = $(this).attr('data-myclub');
        var lastname = $('input[name=lastname]').val();
        var firstname = $('input[name=firstname]').val();
        var importance = $('input[name=importance]').val();
        var dataString = 'myseason=' + myseason + '&update=1&' + 'myplayer=' + myplayer + '&' + 'myclub=' + myclub + '&' + 'lastname' + myplayer + '=' + lastname + '&' + 'firstname' + myplayer + '=' + firstname + '&' + 'importance' + myplayer + '=' + importance;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit_clubs.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Sorry, you have right, I have formatted the code, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to base your selections on the button pressed, for instance, you can use the button to find the `<tr>` and then search it for the fields.

```
$('.update').click(function() {

    var myplayer = $(this).attr('data-myplayer');
    var myseason = $(this).attr('data-myseason');
    var myclub = $(this).attr('data-myclub');
    var lastname = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=lastname]').val();
    var firstname = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=firstname]').val();
    var importance = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name=importance]').val();
    // don't build the post data by hand
    //var dataString = 'myseason=' + myseason + '&update=1&' + 'myplayer=' + myplayer + '&' + 'myclub=' + myclub + '&' + 'lastname' + myplayer + '=' + lastname + '&' + 'firstname' + myplayer + '=' + firstname + '&' + 'importance' + myplayer + '=' + importance;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit_clubs.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            myseason: myseason,
            update: '1',
            myplayer: myplayer,
            myclub: myclub,
            ['lastname'+myplayer]: lastname,
            ['firstname'+myplayer]: firstname,
            ['importance'+myplayer]: importance
        },
    });
});
```

Also, id must be unique in a document so you cannot have all the fields in the form have the same ids as all the other forms.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried your code, but lastname, firstname and importance have not posted.

Comment: So, for some reason, the form is closed immediately in the row so none of the fields are in the form. So I changed it to find the row (`<tr>`) instead to do the search for the fields

Comment: Hi, now it works, thank you for your help! It was a big help for me.